# How to make a printer which is recognized but not working print

Tags: debian, printing, cups

I'm running a Debian 6.0. I connected an HP 1000 J110 to my server which I access via SSH. Listing the USB ports it recognized it. Also I Pasted the PPD on the `/etc/cups/ppd/` folder. Is the PPD my PC uses to print when attached directly to the PC. I installed another printer and had no problem.

I Use `lpstat -p` and it shows the printer there :

```
printer DESKJET-1000-J110 is idle.  enabled since Fri 22 Mar 2013 08:05:33 PM UTC
```

Then I use:

```
lp -d DESKJET-1000-J110 filetoprint.txt
```

where DESKJET-1000-J110-111 is the request id (1 file), and it appears that the file is sent to the printer. It actually appears as completed, but it just doesn't print anything.

I also tryed with HPLip And when trying to run `hp-setup` it says:

```
error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.
```

I checked and this printer *is* supported by HPLip.  What am I missing? I can post any additional needed info

Comment: Check `/var/log/cups/error_log`. If it doesn't say anything, up the LogLevel in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`. Also, what user did you run hp-setup as? Did said user (if non-root) have access to the USB port? It should work: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet/deskjet_1000_j110_series.html

Comment: Thank you a lot... that error log helped me a lot... I resolved the problem... actually I have tryed already what solved the problem... i'm a little confused... but it work now. I'll post my solution

Comment: @derobert Another thing.. I'm using this printer for multiple clients and I use the IP as reference. How can I use a hostname for the server to make this? I'm using the hostname that is in the `/etc/hostname` file of my server. But no pc can find it... is it ok this way?

Comment: If they're running CUPS, you should be able to publish the printer on the server, then turn on browsing on the clients, and it'll automatically work. Other than that, you need to get the hostname resolvable—e.g., add it to your DNS server. If they're Windows clients, you can also use Samba. I suggest opening a new question with full details if that doesn't answer it.

Comment: Yes, browsing is on.. i need to make some tests. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was not that complicated. I used the following code: (Erased before the existing printers using lpadmin -x PrinterName)

To view my URI:

```
lpinfo -v
```

I got this:

```
:~# lpinfo -v
network http
network socket
direct scsi
network lpd
network ipp
serial serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
direct usb://HP/Deskjet%201000%20J110%20series?serial=CN19S21RWB05D2
network beh
```

The `direct usb` part is the URI.

I had already a ppd file. So I copied it to `/etc/cups/ppd/`

Then I added the printer using:

```
:~# lpadmin -p Deskjet-1000-J110-series -E -v usb://HP/Deskjet%201000%20J110%20series?serial=CN19S21RWB05D2 -m /etc/cups/ppd/Deskjet-1000-J110-series.ppd
```

I got this error:
`lpadmin: Unable to copy PPD file!`

As it was already specified (the ppd file) .. I ran a test

`lp -d Deskjet-1000-J110-series fileToPrint`

And.. printed...

Answer (score 0):

To install HP All in One go to terminal:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/hplip/hplip-3.13.11.run
chmod +x hplip-3.13.11.run
sh hplip-3.13.11.run
```

for root password type in terminal:

```
sudo passwd root
```